# How to write JS code so that intellisense pick up included files at run time

Tags: javascript, intellisense

I wrote an API wrapper in Node.JS where I broke out the different calls in various files for organizations sake. Instead of including them statically I was wanting to write a function to iterate through all of the files and include them at runtime.

However, when I did this, I noticed that VSCs intellisense no longer was able to pick up the functions in the included files.

Is there a way to do this so that intellisense is able to pick it up?

This is the current way I am including the call files.

```
    this.usage = require('./calls/usage')(this);
    this.users = require('./calls/users')(this);
    this.groups = require('./calls/groups')(this);
    this.exams = require('./calls/exams')(this);
    this.events = require('./calls/events')(this);
    this.dashboard = require('./calls/dashboard')(this);
    this.curriculums = require('./calls/curriculums')(this);
    this.courses = require('./calls/courses')(this);
    this.content = require('./calls/content')(this);
    this.badges = require('./calls/badges')(this);
```

This is the preferred route but again, when doing it this way it broke the intellisense in VSC.

```
 _loadCalls() {
     const callsDirectory = path.join(__dirname, 'calls');
     const files = fs.readdirSync(callsDirectory);

     files.forEach(file => {
       const fileName = path.parse(file).name;
       const funcName = fileName.replace('.js', '');

       this[funcName] = require(`./calls/${fileName}`)(this);
     });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `require` dynamically breaks code bundling tools. Your desired approach is unlikely to work.

Modularized JavaScript code is first bundled before it's executed, probably by webpack or a similar code bundling tool. By making the `require` call dynamic, the code bundler doesn't know what to do with it, so the extra files you need don't become available. Additionally intellisense also doesn't know what to make of it because it can't predict the result of a dynamic `require` call.

Are you looking for a way to split your code into multiple parts that don't all need to be loaded initially? This can be done but it can gets complicated quickly and is really only needed in extremely high performance situations.

You could also look into using `import` instead of `require`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was just looking to load them dynamically in case this company adds additional endpoints in the future. I wouldn't have to modify the main files anymore. It isn't really that big of a deal, just trying to learn as I go :).

I haven't learned all the ins and outs of ES5 but I'll give it a shot on converting to use import. Thanks!